# Varias ImageView dentro FrameLayout , ocorre um erro

Tags: java, android, xml

Bom o problema é o seguinte tenho algumas `ImageView` que são chamadas por botões, funcionado legal, mas ao definir 4 imagens ele ainda vai bem, adiciono mais uma `ImageView`com outra imagem ai o programa da erro, nessa mesma `ImagemView` coloco uma imagem das 4 o programa roda porque isso ocorre?

Logcat:

```
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Process: com.teste.testeaplicao, PID: 767
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.teste.testeaplicacao/com.teste.testeaplicao.Teste}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.teste.testeaplicacao.Teste.onCreate(Teste.java:40)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 11 more
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 24 more
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
02-01 17:53:07.950: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 27 more
```

Comment: Fica um pouco complicado saber qual o problema. Poderia incluir o **stacktrace** do erro e/ou o código que adiciona essas imagens?

Comment: Nesse caso é um erro sim, alguma `Exception` ocorre que força o fechamento do app. Não aparece nada no *logcat* da sua IDE?

Comment: A princípio não vejo erro nenhum nesse layout. Acho que vale a pena você investigar o problema que ocorreu. Consegue ter acesso ao log da IDE para saber o que houve?

Comment: Rodolfo, esse log não ajuda muito, tente pegar o log inteiro do erro, em geral ele tem mais de 10 linhas.

Comment: Você teve um `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` na recuperação das imagens. Isso significa que faltou memória para alocação durante o carregamento das imagens. Qual o tamanho dessas imagens? Não tem como reduzir?

Comment: todas ela juntas da 13 MB

Comment: você ta falando da resolução da imagem? tem como aumentar a memoria para que fucione

Comment: É bastante coisa. O Android disponibiliza de 16 a 32 MB de memória por padrão. Para aumentar isso você pode usar a propriedade "largeHeap" no seu manifest. Mas saiba que nunca é bom usar muita memória. Eu recomendo fazer uma otimização, porque pela sua lógica, apenas uma imagem fica visível por vez correto? Seria bom carregar apenas uma imagem na memoria por vez. Entendeu?

Comment: mais ou menos, seria usar uma variável para chamar as imagens? se você poder dar um exemplo?

Comment: a solução pode estar aqui http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: dei uma olhada lá pois encontro dificuldade em aplicar o método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir do seu log podemos analisar que o problema é em questão de memória - `OutOfMemory`.

Geralmente isso ocorre pelo tamanho das imagens que você está tentando renderizar!
Recomendo você redesenhar o design do seu aplicativo.

Notei que você tem um `FrameLayout` que contem um `ImageView` como background. É isso?
Se for, retire isso e use a propriedade `android:background="@drawable/..."`